# Has anyone seen this error? err.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.Errorwritingtopersistedcontenttor

Tags: xpages

On my Domino server (9.0.1, FP2) I am getting the following error.

11/20/2014 01:00:39 PM  HTTP JVM: **!err.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.Errorwritingtopersistedcontenttor!**. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Program Files/IBM/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

When I look in the log-0.xml file I see errors like the following. Anyone else ever see this before? I searched the web and only found something similar back around 8.5.2 days.

```
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2014-11-20T16:49:03.506-05:00" globalInstanceId="ELac14b30a000149b8a6bc5c00000ab2" msg="!err.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.Errorwritingtopersistedcontenttor!" severity="50" version="1.0.1">
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
        <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
            <values>SEVERE</values>
        </children>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
        <values>com.ibm.commons.log.AbstractLogMgr</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
        <values>log</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
        <values>java.lang.NullPointerException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider$PersistenceServiceResource.write(PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.java:105)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesResourceServlet.doGet(FacesResourceServlet.java:110)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesModuleResourceServlet.service(FacesModuleResourceServlet.java:85)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)&#xD;&#xA;</values>
        <values>&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)&#xD;&#xA;</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="st2cnmtl01" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="" threadId="2" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
        <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
    </situation>
</CommonBaseEvent>
```

Comment: @RyanVincent: Let me summarize your comment: "I have no idea".

Comment: @Ryan, that was my first step... hence why I am now asking on SO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The persistence provider is used when files on the disks are accessed. This can be persisteted attachments (for CKEditor) or global resources like JS libraries or CSS files (stored in *notesdata/domino/*)

In your case, it seems that a resource could not be found / is missed. Please check all URLs (e.g. with a Firefox extension like Firebug to sniff the traffic between client and server) which the browser wants to open before the error occurs. The URL should contain a */.ibmxspres/*.

**UPDATE:**

The error can also occur because of an attachment in a RichText item. When you open a CK Editor, all files are detached to disk in a persistence folder, so the CK Editor can display them (or the files can be downloaded)

As soon you open a URL with *xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/*, the resource servlet will try to open the file at the end of the URL (*/DominoDoc-CD2-Body/_1_14129733906‌​540-76E.gif*) and send it back to the client. But when a session times out, or the server is restarted, these persisted files are discarded from disk and are no longer available.

In your case, the Bing Bot has crawled your page and found such an persisted file. And now he wants to check if this file still exists (which is no longer the case). That's why the servlet throws an error.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks, what is the f.e. (a firebug extension?), Howard

Comment: Argh! Sorry for my bad English. "E.g." not f.e.

Comment: I tried tracing the time the error shows up in the Domino log.nsf to the web log for the same time and then tried the urls. The error was not repeated and the page resources all loaded. So, not really able to pinpoint what is throwing the error.

Comment: After a little more digging and converting to GMT time (Domino log is at server time zone and my web logs were set to record time using GMT). I found that the issue appears to be search engines looking for a non-existent resource. Not sure why but at least I know it is nothing in my code or for a useful page. Below is one request that causes the error.

Comment: 207.46.13.21 www.tlcc.com - [20/Nov/2014:18:15:30 +0000] "GET /admin/tlccsite.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-CD2-Body/_1_14129733906540-76E.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" 0 "" "D:/Program Files/IBM/Lotus/Domino/data/admin/tlccsite.nsf"

Comment: @Howard: Ah, OK. I thought it was a resource file because of the *FacesResourceServlet* in the trace log. I update my answer.

Comment: Notice: I get this error message also on a `domino 8.5.3 FP6` server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sven's info. and some digging it appears there is no issue with our environment, just bots trying to access resources that are no longer available.

Howard

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web server's robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *SessionID=*
Disallow: /yourwebsite.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/
```

and use Google's WebMaster tool to tell Google that your robots.txt has changed. Instantly no more error messages!