# HTTP Code : 500 XPage Error

Tags: xpages

We are getting the error like this

```
12/06/2015 14:42:35   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

12/06/2015 14:42:35   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/ckeditor.js - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

12/06/2015 14:42:36   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

12/06/2015 14:42:36   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/skins/lotus21/editor.css - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

or

```
12/06/2015 16:22:37   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

12/06/2015 16:22:37   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /ASAP/helpdesk2000.nsf/xpASAPRequest.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in F:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

12/06/2015 16:22:38   HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception [/path/db.nsf/xpage.xsp?documentId=BE7D455563ECAD9DC1257E5F0031A703&action=editDocument&viewname=abc&$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3AidAssignTo] CN=user name/OU=OrgUnit../OU=OrgUnit../OU=OrgUnit../O=Org..
```

This does not happen always but happens 6 to 8 times every day.
Please help to identify the reason and how to rectify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpages HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception HTTP Code: 500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271653/xpages-http-web-server-command-not-handled-exception-http-code-500)

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what you were doing when it happened. Also, are the errors thrown when using it in the browser or in the Notes client? What versions of client and server software are in use?

Comment: This not happening always only 6 to 8 times every days, some times to open a view in xpage ; sometime during partial refresh, some time saving a document. Most of the times it works only happens in a very less cases; it is not possible to produce.

Answer (score 5):

An error 500 points at some server logic failing. In your case this could be some SSJS (Serverside JavaScript) or Java that fails. Your first step in identifying the problem is to have a look at the error logs as stated in the message. That can be a little tedious to get to as these files sit in the file system on the server.

However, there is an OpenNTF project to help you! It is called "[OpenNTF Log File Reader](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8UXP49)". Follow this link where you will find a short video about it - and a download link ;-)

Once you identified the code that throws the error you have many different options for identifying the issue ranging from adding a "print" statement to doing a remote debug (which you should only do on a development server though).

/John

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletResponse.reset(XspCmdHttpServletResponse.java:851)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.servlet.LCDAdapterHttpServletResponse.reset(LCDAdapterHttpServletResponse.java:209)
 at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesResourceServlet.service404(FacesResourceServlet.java:136)
 at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesResourceServlet.doGet(FacesResourceServlet.java:113)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)

Comment: at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesGlobalResourceServlet.service(FacesGlobalResourceServlet.java:83)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:860)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)

Comment: at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
 at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.StaticResourcesService.doService(StaticResourcesService.java:63)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
 at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Comment: I have pasted xpage error log for the same, I do not now which part of the code generates that and where I would put print.

Comment: Hi... it is really difficult to tell exactly where the problem is. However, "com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesResourceServlet.service404" springs into the eyes... Seems something cannot be found. Try to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050606/has-anyone-seen-this-error-err-persistenceserviceresourceprovider-errorwritingt - maybe it is related?

Comment: @SubhasishMukhopadhyay: comments is not really an ideal format to render log files. Would you please add them to your question? Please also add your code pertaining to those stacktraces as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , and I resolved it ssjs side. There was no info in "/workspace/logs/error-log-0.xml" . file I commented my new code one by one, then I found the coding error and fixed it.